# Distribute circles evenly along a curve

Tags: animation, objects, bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I need the circles to appear from the center with a gap equal to one circle and at the end gather towards each other

[image] Here the circles came out from the center one by one with distance from each other

[image] And then they reached the end and in turn began to lean against each other

Comment: And what did u try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version assumes you want to make your instances appear at one end of the curve, move along it at fixed intervals, and accumulate at the other end:

This GN group modifies the curve, and distributes `Count` instances along it, with a given `Gap` between them, at a given `Offset`. Animating the `Offset` will move the instances along the curve.

[image]

It samples the input curve at `(reversed-instance-index * gap) + offset` length, retrieving that position, at which to locate the instances. Left to itself, that would clump the instances at the endpoints of the curve, so two adjustments are made:

- The sample-length is clamped for each instance at `(curve-length - instance-index * instance-width)`
- If the offset sampled  length is 0 or less, the instances are deleted.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what is needed!

Answer (score 2):

It looks pretty straight-forward, divide the length of the curve by the number of circles:

[image]

If you need to adjust the circle size so the circles touch, just set the circle diameter to the obtained segment length (the node has radius input, which is half of a diameter so I divide by 2):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Geometry Nodes

[image: Original Question] [image: Mistake with gif creation]

Images above.  Left side image to meet original question goals.  Right side image with a random exploration of geometry nodes with a reversed last to first gif adventure.

[image]

Above image. Geometry modifier values.  Like all geometry modifiers, changing the values in the modifiers can give various results.  The results need not be limited to the original question.  Limited value testing.  Please inspect and modify to suit your tastes on your computer.

- First two count values should be the same.  Number of circular meshes to appear
- Item 03. Frame. When the mesh should appear on curve. Items are more distant on curve to meet original question goals.
- Item 04. Frame. When transition should appear.  Items can be spaced closer after this frame as time increases, to meet original question goals.
- Item 05. End Frame.  When items are closest end of curve potentially, to meet original question goals.
- Item 06-09. Curve Trim values. Begin and End values. Range of curve occupation. Value in the range [0.0,1.0].  Range 1 < Range 2 to meet original question goals.

Image above.  Thumbnail in upper left is guide.

[image]

[image]

Image above.  Nodes for group or function.